# Typescript: Specify a parent class type to his childs

Tags: typescript, inheritance

## Problem

I want to create a JSON object that has 3 kinda of objects (all from the same parent object) as values.
And, I want to specify their types.
I want to do this to the Intellisense help-me with my code using the functions from the parent class...

## Example:

```js
abstract class Parent{
    function do_something() {...}
}

class child_1 extends Parent{}
class child_2 extends Parent{}
class child_3 extends Parent{}

// Now the JSON
const json: {[key: string]: /*WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE*/} = {
    'child_1': child_1,
    'child_2': child_2,
    'child_3': child_3,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "JSON object" you mean a JavaScript object, since that's what your example code includes. I also assume that you intend each value you in the object to be an *instance* of one of the child classes rather than the class itself.

TypeScript should already infer the type of your `json` object, and if you have your editor configured to use TypeScript's language server, you'll get IntelliSense suggestions for methods on each value in the object.

Here is a cleaned up version of your example to demonstrate:

```
abstract class Parent {
  parentMethod() {}
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  child1Method() {}
}

const children = {
  child1: new Child1(),
};

// Both of these methods on `child1` will be suggested by Intellisense
children.child1.parentMethod();
children.child1.child1Method();
```

If you want to enforce that every value in the object is a `Parent`, you can type it like this:

```
const children: { [index: string]: Parent } = {
  child1: new Child1(),
  child2: new Child2(),
  child3: new Child3(),
};
```

However, if you do it this way, you'll only be able to access the methods from `Parent` on the `child1` property, because you've typed the property as a `Parent` rather than as a `Child`.

If you don't want to widen the type of each property to `Parent`, you'll have to specify the index type as a union of all possible children:

```
const children: { [index: string]: Child1 | Child2 | Child3 } = {
  child1: new Child1(),
  child2: new Child2(),
  child3: new Child3(),
};
```

If you use this form, you can call the methods from `Parent` on any of the properties of the object, but you'll need to use a type guard to check which specific class each property is before using any methods that are specific to a particular child class.